# What's the difference of tns and ns in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

I'm just learning nativescript now and I saw some examples use `tns` and another is `ns` what's the difference? Which one should I really be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same, `ns` is the new standard as of NativeScript 7 which was released in August 2020.

As mentioned in this [blogpost](https://blog.nativescript.org/nativescript-7-announcement/index.html), `tns` will always work for historical reason, and `ns` is the new standard. There is also `nsc` which should work the same way.

Comment: And to confirm it, if you do a `ls -l` on the executables (in linux) you will see that both are links that point to `../lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin/tns`.